# How to get the HTML source code of a URL via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

We have a monitoring tool known as Sitescope, which can be accessed via below mentioned link (private URL, mentioned for your reference) via IE or Chrome. The credentials which are required to login to this application are embedded inside the URL. So if you paste this URL in IE or chrome, then it will initially goto login page and automatically redirect to the second page (in the below URL, the redirecting page is, application's "about page"). I need help to get the HTML source code of the about page (which is redirected automatically.

URL: https://chcnm6027.dir.svc.accenture.com:8443/SiteScope/jsp/about_sitescope.jsp?sis_silent_login_type=encrypted&login=(sisp)aXFxQre%2BtNc%3D&password=(sisp)xWoZQ/XddqR5HldzKTC%2B9A%3D%3D

When I tried to use the below PowerShell script, it can able to download the source code of first page, nothing but the login page, but I need the source code for second page, which is automatically redirecting.

Script I used given below.

```
$url = "https://chcnm6027.dir.svc.accenture.com:8443/SiteScope/jsp/about_sitescope.jsp?sis_silent_login_type=encrypted&login=(sisp)aXFxQre%2BtNc%3D&password=(sisp)xWoZQ/XddqR5HldzKTC%2B9A%3D%3D"
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$rawHTML = $webClient.DownloadString($url)
echo $rawHTML
```

Comment: You could try to re-elaborate your question in an easier way please, because it's hard (at least for me) to understand what are you are trying to explain here. Furthermore, the link is unreachable (I guess it's a private place maybe?). Thanks

Comment: Inspect the communication between your browser and the web server with something [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/), or something similar, then re-create that communication in PowerShell.